# Selecting distinct random items from a list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a rummy program in python 3.8, And a have a set list of all the possible cards, how do I pick 13 random **distinct** cards such that once those cards are chosen by the player, the other player cannot receive them?

For example

```
card =['Ah','Ad','Ac','As','2h','2d','2c','2s','3h','3d','3c','3s','4h','4d','4c','4s','5h','5d','5c','5s','6h','6d','6c','6s','7h','7d','7c','7s','8h','8d','8c','8s','9d','9c','9h','9s','10h','10d','10c','10s','Jh','Jd','Jc','Js','Qh','Qd','Qc','Qs','Kh','Kd','Kc','Ks','Joker1','Joker2']

n1=[random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),random.choice(card),]
```

if this command is done, the cards are not distinct, Kc can be repeated twice in the 13 cards

can you please help me?

Comment: use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) which selects unique values:

```
from random import sample

card = ['Ah','Ad','Ac','As','2h','2d','2c','2s','3h','3d','3c','3s','4h','4d','4c','4s','5h','5d','5c','5s','6h','6d','6c','6s','7h','7d','7c','7s','8h','8d','8c','8s','9d','9c','9h','9s','10h','10d','10c','10s','Jh','Jd','Jc','Js','Qh','Qd','Qc','Qs','Kh','Kd','Kc','Ks','Joker1','Joker2']

# e.g.
player_1_selected = sample(card, 13)
# ['5s', '10c', 'As', '2h', 'Qh', 'Kc', '10s', '4h', 'Qc', '9h', '8c', '4d', '3s']
print(player_1_selected)

remaining_to_select = list(set(card) - set(player_1_selected))
# ['3c', 'Ac', 'Qs', '6h', '9s', '7s', '5c', '3h', 'Ad', 'Qd', '9d', '7h', '10d', '6d', '2d', '3d', '5h', '7d', '6c', 'Kd', '2s', 'Jh', '8s', '9c', 'Kh', '6s', 'Ah', '10h', 'Jd', '7c', 'Ks', '4c', '2c', 'Joker2', '8h', '8d', 'Jc', 'Js', 'Joker1', '5d', '4s']
print(remaining_to_select)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but how can I prevent other players from picking the 13 cards that I have?

Comment: Thanks ! that was helpful.

Comment: Welcome @NandhithKarthikeyan :) You can mark as solved now

Comment: TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not list

Comment: What is the command to pick 13 random elements from a Tuple?

Comment: Using `sample` as I've demonstrated above, it works both on sets and lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import random

card =['Ah','Ad','Ac','As','2h','2d','2c','2s','3h','3d','3c','3s','4h','4d','4c','4s','5h','5d','5c','5s','6h','6d','6c','6s','7h','7d','7c','7s','8h','8d','8c','8s','9d','9c','9h','9s','10h','10d','10c','10s','Jh','Jd','Jc','Js','Qh','Qd','Qc','Qs','Kh','Kd','Kc','Ks','Joker1','Joker2']

n1=[]

for x in range(13):
    n1.append(cards[random.randrange(len(cards))])
```

Comment: This is broken in several ways. First, it doesn't stop duplicates and second, `randrange` is going to give you more results than you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code;

```
import random
cards = ['Ah', 'Ad', 'Ac', 'As', '2h', '2d', '2c', '2s', '3h', '3d', '3c', '3s', '4h', '4d', '4c', '4s', '5h', '5d',
        '5c', '5s', '6h', '6d', '6c', '6s', '7h', '7d', '7c', '7s', '8h', '8d', '8c', '8s', '9d', '9c', '9h', '9s',
        '10h', '10d', '10c', '10s', 'Jh', 'Jd', 'Jc', 'Js', 'Qh', 'Qd', 'Qc', 'Qs', 'Kh', 'Kd', 'Kc', 'Ks', 'Joker1',
        'Joker2']

n1 = random.sample(cards, 13)

print(n1)
```